# VBF Redirect RichTextBox data to a file

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've created a VB form in VS 2017 which is based on an example I found by Kelvin Le.  I have it working with data being returned displayed in the outputTextBox (see code below).  What I want to do is have the remote device send a lot (MBytes) of data that will be saved into a file (I've written and can modify the code for the remote device so I have full control over how it's sent).

I suppose the received stream could spool through the outputTextBox but what I really want is to have a button that opens a file eg dumpfile01.txt and sends a command eg "DF01"to the serial device which will then stream the file contents - I'd like to make the button also switch the serial stream of data straight to the file and have some specific sequence in the stream recognized that says the stream is over, at which point the file is closed and saved and the serial data is directed back to the outputTextBox.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class Form1
    '------------------------------------------------
    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiving of data
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        portComboBox.Items.AddRange(myPort)

        writeButton.Enabled = False

    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub portComboBox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles portComboBox.Click
    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub initButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles InitButton.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = portComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = baudComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()
        InitButton.Enabled = False
        writeButton.Enabled = True
        CloseButton.Enabled = True

    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub writeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write(inputTextBox.Text & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n
    End Sub

    Private Sub closeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        InitButton.Enabled = True
        writeButton.Enabled = False
        CloseButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
        If Me.outputTextBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else

            Me.outputTextBox.AppendText([text])
            Me.outputTextBox.ScrollToCaret()


        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub dirButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dirButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write("DI" & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n
    End Sub
End Class
```

OK I made it sort of work and my new code is below.  What I do is use a button called modeButton to toggle between mode 0 (stream goes to textbox) or mode 1 (stream goes to file).  It works but I think that my code is flaky and that I should probably close the file out?
I am not sure what happens in the ReceivedText2 Sub when a stream is being received, is that second 'using writer as streamwriter' section called for every character or every line? The counter value I see is like 5 for 1,000s of characters received which makes me think it's per line.
I'd also like to find a way to check the data stream for a specific sequence so I can detect EOF.
Any help appreciated and hopefully this might help someone too.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class Form1
    Public dataMode As Integer = 0
    Public myCounter As Int32 = 0

    Dim path As String = "c:\tempgf\MyTest.txt"

    '------------------------------------------------
    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiving of data
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        portComboBox.Items.AddRange(myPort)
        writeButton.Enabled = False

    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub portComboBox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles portComboBox.Click
    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub initButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles InitButton.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = portComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = baudComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()
        InitButton.Enabled = False
        writeButton.Enabled = True
        CloseButton.Enabled = True

    End Sub
    '------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub writeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write(inputTextBox.Text & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n
    End Sub

    Private Sub closeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        InitButton.Enabled = True
        writeButton.Enabled = False
        CloseButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        If dataMode = 0 Then
            ReceivedText1(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
        Else ' this applies if dataMode != 0
            ReceivedText2(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText1(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
        ' handles output to outputTextBox
        If Me.outputTextBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText1)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.outputTextBox.AppendText([text])
            Me.outputTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceivedText2(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
        ' handles output to file
        If Not File.Exists(path) Then
            ' Create a file to write to.
            Using writer As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(path) ' path is defined at start of code
                writer.WriteLine("Garfield Data File")
            End Using
        End If
        Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(path)
            writer.Write([text])
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
        End Using
    End Sub
    Private Sub dirButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dirButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write("DI" & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n
    End Sub

    Private Sub modeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles modeButton.Click
        If dataMode = 0 Then
            dataMode = 1
            Me.outputTextBox.Text = "mode set to file"
            myCounter = 0

        Else
            dataMode = 0
            Me.outputTextBox.Text = "mode set to here"
            Me.outputTextBox.Text = myCounter
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What I really need help with is understanding how the Delegate functionality operates, I'm scared to alter it because I don't get how it works.

Comment: Updated my original comment - the (sort of) working code is at the end.

Comment: Ted....Delegate functions are kind of outdated, since about .Net 2.0.  They can still be used but in very far and few scenarios, now a days.  In short Delegates are nothing more than Header-like (*.h) signatures for methods.  If you only use the Delegate once, use a Lambda expression pseudo-method (function or sub) to perform the operation.  The scenarios to best describe Delegates are Form Events.  Most have a standard signature `sender as object, e as EventArgs`